# PDF and doc file selection restriction in google drive

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I have implemented Angular Google Picker [google Picker](https://github.com/softmonkeyjapan/angular-google-picker). Can I apply, user can only select pdf and doc from google picker no other file.

Please help me to do this.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can. PDFs, Spreadsheets, Images are examples of mimetypes. You can control the View of your MiMEType preference by using [google.picker.​ViewId](https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/#otherviews). + MiMEType. Example:

> - Adobe PDF files stored in Google Drive is    google.picker.​ViewId.PDFS
> - Google Drive photos is    google.picker.​ViewId.DOCS_IMAGES Google Drive
> - Documents is google.picker.​ViewId.DOCUMENTS

I played with this and displayed the Folders (in your case, PDFs) using

```
function createPicker() {
        // Create a view to search Folders.
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS);
        // Use DocsUploadView to upload documents to Google Drive.
        var uploadView = new google.picker.DocsUploadView();

        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
            addView(view).
            setAppId(appId).
            setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
            setCallback(pickerCallback).
            build();
        picker.setVisible(true);
    }
```

For you, use this line instead:

```
 var view = new google.picker.View( google.picker.​ViewId.PDFS);
```

I used plain JS for this, it's up to you to implement in Angular.